# Acrobat JavaScript this.submit(url, false) does not work on Chrome PDF Viewer

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-javascript

I have a PDF document, using a button on the form I submit to a URL using 
        this.submitForm(url, false);
works fine with Adobe Reader Plugin but not with Chrome PDF Viewer, does Chrome PDF Viewer submit forms using a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has its own PDF viewer called Chrome PDF Viewer, and AcroJS won't work (mostly) on Chrome PDF Viewer. One needs to detect the plug-in, and force the user to use Acrobat Reader if the browser is Chrome's own.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting forms is an not yet implemented feature of Chrome PDF Viewer. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65446 for Details and (missing) progress and star it to push dev's interest.